# Laravel 5.4 passport not found route

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel Framework version 5.4.36 and i have setup success passport,i have run command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-components
```

My routes:

```
| Domain | Method   | URI                                     | Name       | Action                                                                     | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                                       |            | Closure                                                                    | web          |
|        | POST     | api/details                             |            | App\Http\Controllers\API\UserController@details                            | api,auth:api |
|        | POST     | api/login                               |            | App\Http\Controllers\API\UserController@login                              | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/loginError                          | loginError | App\Http\Controllers\API\UserController@loginError                         | api          |
|        | POST     | api/register                            |            | App\Http\Controllers\API\UserController@register                           | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/test                                | test       | App\Http\Controllers\API\UserController@test                               | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user                                |            | Closure                                                                    | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                                    | home       | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                                  | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/authorize                         |            | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController@authorize       | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | oauth/authorize                         |            | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ApproveAuthorizationController@approve  | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/authorize                         |            | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\DenyAuthorizationController@deny        | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | oauth/clients                           |            | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@store                  | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/clients                           |            | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@forUser                | web,auth     |
|        | PUT      | oauth/clients/{client_id}               |            | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@update                 | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/clients/{client_id}               |            | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@destroy                | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/personal-access-tokens            |            | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@forUser   | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | oauth/personal-access-tokens            |            | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@store     | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/personal-access-tokens/{token_id} |            | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@destroy   | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/scopes                            |            | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ScopeController@all                     | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | oauth/token                             |            | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken        | throttle     |
|        | POST     | oauth/token/refresh                     |            | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\TransientTokenController@refresh        | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/tokens                            |            | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@forUser | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/tokens/{token_id}                 |            | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@destroy | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | testOracle                              | testOracle | App\Http\Controllers\WellcomeController@testOracle                         | web          |
```

I cannot found get uri oauth/clients,it is in action  `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@forUser`,
My error is cannot found action `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@forUser`,
when i have go to folder vendor,i only see `vendor\laravel\passport` 
[passport folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtrJg.png) 
it is not have link \Laravel\Passport\Http`

How can i fix this error,thank you

Comment: `vendor\laravel\passport\src\...`

Answer (score 0):

Go to [\vendor\laravel\passport\src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vWLv.png) folder. You will find Http folder there.

[image]